# rxjs_1 isObservable is not a function while running angular application

Tags: angular

We have created angular4 application using node version 8 and now updated node version 10.In node older version my application will run properly .After updated node version am getting below error while running the application

ng serve -- open

rxjs_1 isObservable is not a function while running angular application

Can anybody tell how to fix the error

Thanks

Comment: Might be issue of rxjs compatibility

Comment: @PrashantPimpale how to fix this issue

Comment: I am not sure about it...you might have to search it

Answer (score 0):

Try `rxjs-compat` library. It allows you using older versions of rxjs in updated apps.